# how to get 5-day weather forecast by using woeid

Tags: yahoo, weather

I get weather from yahoo by WOEID with link http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=20079323 and it ok, but xml file return only 2 forecast. So, how to get 5 day weather forecast by using WOEID.

Answer (score 1):

See this link.. This may help you, I got my app working through this.

[Yahoo Weather API](http://androidcodebits.wordpress.com/2013/07/20/integration-of-yahoo-weather-api-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible, see [Weather API Reference](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#params).  Only 2 options (temperature unit, and WOEID)

Answer (score 0):

Well isn't this late...

I don't know if this is precisely what you're looking for, but use this URL:

> http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/forecastrss/20079323_c.xml

Replace `_c` with `_f` and you'll get farenheit units.